# Proving a Borel measure is $\sigma$-finite

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, borel-sets, borel-measures

Let $\mu$ be the Lebesgue measure on ($\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{B_R})$. Define a Borel measure as follows:

$\displaystyle v(E) = \int_E \frac{1}{|x|} d\mu(x)$.

How do I prove that $v$ is $\sigma$-finite? I am confused on how to compute $v$ in general. For instance, what would $v(\{0\})$ be? Is it undefined because $\frac{1}{|x|}$ is undefined at $x = 0$?

The most obvious decomposition would be the union of $[-i, i]$, but I am quite sure that this is not finite because as $x$ grows small, $\frac{1}{x}$ grows large.

Comment: Could you elaborate @Surb?

Comment: @Surb What about a decomposition such as $[1/(n+1), 1/n]$ for the small values? This avoids the zero and I believe each of these is finite (the integral is less than $1/n$)

Comment: Could you explain why $v\{0\} = 0$? I think if this is true, then you can use this decomposition along with consecutive integers $([n, n+1])$, and do the same for the negative integers. Each will be finite. The only number leftover is $0$, but if it too is finite, then we should be okay.

Comment: indeed, it works. Sorry for having giving you a wrong hint.

Comment: $\nu\{0\}=0$ because $\{0\}$ has measure $0$ w.r.t. lebesgue measure.

Comment: But what I do not understand is how is $v$ even defined on sets containing $\{0\}$ when the integrand is not defined at $0$.

Comment: You can define it at $0$ by giving any value. At the end it's not so important the value at $0$ since integral doesn't see sets null sets... You can also define $\frac{1}{|x|}=\infty $ when $x=0$.

Comment: Your doubt about $[-i,i]$ is justified.  $v([-i,i]) = \infty$ if $i>0$.